# Saving Dynamically Generated PHP Calculations to A MySQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a page with with the following php code:

```
<?php                         
 include ('dbconnect.php');  

// get values from the form
  function getPosts()
    {
     $posts = array();
     $posts[0] = $_POST['bookingid'];
     $posts[1] = $_POST['bookingname'];
     $posts[2] = $_POST['cabintype'];
     $posts[3] = $_POST['lengthofstay'];
     $posts[4] = $_POST['guests_description'];       
     $posts[5] = $_POST['startdate'];
     $posts[6] = $_POST['enddate'];
     $posts[7] = $_POST['other_information'];
     return $posts;
    } 

 if (isset($_POST['bookingdetails'])) {  

 $data = getPosts();

  $insert_Query = "insert into bookings(Bookingid,Bookingname,Cabin_Type,
  lengthofstay,Details_about_guests,Booking_start_date,Booking_end_date,
  Other_relavant_information)
  values ('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]',
         '$data[6]','$data[7]')";

  $result = mysqli_query($db, $insert_Query);

 if ($result){
   echo "<p>Total price is \$$total</p>\n";
   Booked</p> </font>";
 }else{
  echo "<p> Something went Wrong! Contact Your Administrator </p>" . 
  mysqli_error ($db);
 }
}

$Luxury_Cabin= 1200;
$Contemporary_Cabin= 1000;
$Original_Cabin= 800;
$Total= "";

if(isset($_POST['bookingdetails']) && $_POST['luxurycabin']=='1')
{
$num=(int)$_POST['lengthofstay']; 
if($num>=0) 
 {
  $Total=($Luxury_Cabin*$num);
 }
}

if(isset($_POST['bookingdetails']) && $_POST['contemporarycabin']=='2')
{
$num=(int)$_POST['lengthofstay']; 
if($num>=0) 
 {
    $Total=($Contemporary_Cabin*$num);
 }
}

if(isset($_POST['bookingdetails']) && $_POST['originalcabin']=='4')
{
$num=(int)$_POST['lengthofstay']; 
if($num>=0)
{
  $Total=($Original_Cabin*$num);
 }
}

echo "<p>Total price is \$$total</p>\n";
?>
```

And the HTML Code is like the following:

```
<form method = "post" action = "" > 

  <tr>
   <th>Bookingid </th>
   <td><input type = "text" name = "bookingid" /> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <th>Booking Name </th>
   <td><input type = "text" name = "bookingname" /> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <th>Cabin Type </th>
   <td><input type = "text" name = "cabintype" /> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <th>Luxury Cabin</th>
   <td><input  type="radio" name="luxurycabin" value="1" />Yes</td>
   <td><input  type="radio" name="luxurycabin" value="0" 
   checked="checked"/>No</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <th>Contemporary Cabin</th>
   <td><input  type="radio" name="contemporarycabin" value="2" />Yes</td>
   <td><input  type="radio" name="contemporarycabin" value="3" 
   checked="checked"/>No</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <th>Original Cabin</th>
   <td><input  type="radio" name="originalcabin" value="4" />Yes</td>
   <td><input  type="radio" name="originalcabin" value="5" 
    checked="checked"/>No</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Length of Stay </th>
    <td><input type = "text" name = "lengthofstay" id="lengthofstay"/> </td>
    </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Details About Guests </th>
    <td><textarea cols = "30" rows = "5" type = "text" name 
    ="guests_description" /></textarea> </td>
  </tr> 

  <tr>
    <th>Booking Start Date </th>
    <td><input type = "text" name = "startdate" /> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>Booking End Date </th>
    <td><input type = "text" name = "enddate" /> </td>
  </tr> 

  <tr>
   <th>Other Relavant Information </th>
   <td><textarea cols = "30" rows = "5" type = "text" name 
   ="other_information" /></textarea> </td>
  </tr>          

   <tr>
    <th> </th>
    <td> <input type = "submit" value = "Create Booking!" name = 
      "bookingdetails" /> </td>
   </tr> 

</table>             
</form>
```

What occurs here is that when the "bookingdetails" button is pressed all of the data entered into the form are sent to the database. What is also done is a multiplication calculation which uses the radio buttons and the number entered into the lenghtofstay field. The result is then echoed on the page itself using:

```
<?php echo "<p>Total price is \£$total</p>\n"; ?>
```

So what I need your assistance with is how do I get the dynamically generated calculation result into my database table with a column called Booking_Price?

Comment: For starters, you already have an error happening in here `if ($result){
   echo "<p>Total price is \$$total</p>\n";
   Booked</p> </font>";`.

Comment: The double dollar sign was also part of the problem. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just swap your code around so all the calculation stuff happens before the database insert and then you have your value to insert in `$total`. Modify your insert query to include it.

Comment: I tried it that way but it did not work all I got was an undefined index. All the values were being stored except the Total_Price, but your answer gave me an idea. All I did was do the calculation first as you said but just echoed the $Total into a separate calculation field then submit the data into the database and it worked perfectly. I am not not sure it is the right way but it worked. Thanks for the help.